# Find the unit vector, which is perpendicular to 2 vectors.

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors

How to solve the following problem:

You're given 2 vectors:

$$ \begin{equation} \alpha = (2; 10; 3) \end{equation} $$
$$ \begin{equation} \beta = (1; 4; 1) \end{equation} $$

Find the unit vector, which is perpendicular to these 2 vectors.

Comment: see [cross product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_product).

Comment: What kind of things have you tried? What do you know that you think might help? Have you studied dot products? cross products?

Comment: There are in fact two such vectors.

Comment: Yes, as you take the square root of it, it's +-, as seen under the answer's comments. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you should do is apply the cross product to the two vectors,

$$\alpha \times \beta $$

The result will be perpendicular to the other two.

If you need a unit vector, you can always scale it down.

Comment: But with that, I do not get the unit vector.

Comment: @Janno divide the resulting vector by its norm

Comment: then you can try $\frac{\alpha x \beta}{|\alpha x \beta|}$

Comment: Thank you. So if I understood you all correctly: The cross product of the 2 vectors is $(-2; 1; -2)$ and I get the unit vector by getting the length of the cross product vector, which is 3, and dividing it the length with the vector, so the unit vector is $ +-(-2/3; 1/3; -2/3)$

Comment: @Janno you are absolutely right.

Comment: Yes it was, big thank you! Also thank you Hassan.

Answer (score 1):

*If you are cross multiplying two vectors then you will always find a vector which will have direction perpendicular to plane of the latter two* (since the new vector is perpendicular to plane of those vectors so it will be perpendicular to each one of them).

In you case, you want to find

> The unit vector perpendicular to vectors α=(2;10;3) and β=(1;4;1).

So for a vector which is perpendicular to α and β, cross multiply α and β. And make it unit vector by dividing it by the magnitude of resultant vector(αXβ).

Hope it help you

Answer (score 0):

Solve the following underdetermined linear system

$$\begin{bmatrix} 2 & 10 & 3\\ 1 & 4 & 1\end{bmatrix} \mathrm x = \begin{bmatrix} 0\\ 0\end{bmatrix}$$

The solution set is a line passing through the origin. Intersect it with the unit Euclidean sphere.